# How to connect Android Studio Login Form using MySQL?

Tags: android, mysql, forms, authentication

So I'm quite new to Java language, but I've programmed alot in C# and C++, since I'm in computer engeenering highschool. My main question is:

How can I connect my app from Android Studio, which Login Form will read from MySQL base, which I've already made. I want the Login Form to read from mySql base, and if it's exactly the same, It'll procced to next page on my app, or Deny acces to the user, if the login name and password are not written correctly.

MySQL database, is already running on a server host : IP: 92.244.93.250:xxxx. 
Do I still need PHP/phpmyadmin or can I connect directly to the mysql?

Im really sorry for my mistakes written in English, since its not my mother language.

I'd really need some advices! :) 
Ty my fellow programmers!:)

Comment: Welcome to SO, for people to be able to help you please show the code you have right now and which part you are having problems with

Comment: Use this for connecting to server and verifying login information. http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html